# Why we should not call public method from another public?

Tags: java

I was told by someone that we should not call a public method of a class from another public method in same class.
 Now i am not able to understand this as i dont see any problem with that.
Once a method has been declared public then its contract is fixed for lifetime and hence there should not be any problem in calling it from another public method.

So I am not sure  if that statement is true or its ok to call public api from another public api [This is from design perspective]?

Comment: I don't know why your question was down-voted, but what that person told you **makes  NO  sense**.

Comment: **So I am not sure if that statement is true or its ok** do a small test yourself, I guess you will get your answer yourself if you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does your compiler balk at you when you try? No? Then it's legal in that respect.

Does the person providing this 'advice' produce any canonical document explaining the standard (either in the industry or within your organisation)? No? Then it's opinion.

Consult your company standards, but otherwise, I call nonsense.

Comment: −1: There are motivations to avoid calling public methods from the inside, whether one agrees with their merit or not. This answer is not helpful in understanding the motivation for the advice.

Answer (score 12):

If you call a public methods from other public methods it makes unit testing more complicated. If one method is depended on another method of the same class you can't mock it to test it separately. So you  may have to write test code for the same method twice.

see also [Unit testing a method that calls another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363596/unit-testing-a-method-that-calls-another-method)

Comment: Do note that the referenced Q/A goes into state handling. If you just write a method that doesn't change the state or if the method is just a simple utility method then the reasoning in that Q/A doesn't really apply. In general you don't want to overcomplicate testing, so I'd prefer fewer / well tested / more generic methods over many methods. Java of course complicates that, but here lambda's may be of some help.

Answer (score 8):

When you very often call public methods from other public methods of the same class, it probably means you have unnecessary utilities methods. And maybe you should try to be a little more DRY so as to ease maintenance and keep your API easy to grasp.

But that's just a warning, it's perfectly valid to call a public method from another one, and you'll find many examples of `java.lang` standard code doing just that.

An example from `java.lang.String` :

```
1462    public boolean startsWith(String prefix) {
1463        return startsWith(prefix, 0);
1464    }
```

There would be no point in making some methods private just to enforce a rule about public methods not calling other public methods.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion you should avoid call a public method within another method because of inheritance. Consider classes:

```
public class Parent {

    //return sum
    public double getSum(double... value){
        //implementation
    }

    //return average
    public double getAverage(int count){
        //call getSum
        double sum = getSum(20, 40, 60);
        return sum / count;

    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {

    @Override
    public int getSum(double... obj){
        // change implementation
        // always return 100;
    }
}
```

If you called on Child object getAverage method, you would get some unexpected value, whole interface of Child object is broken.
You have to override getAverage  method too...

Example with String class

```
1462    public boolean startsWith(String prefix) {
1463        return startsWith(prefix, 0);
1464    }
```

is from this perspective wrong, because string is final, so you can't inherit it and override its public methods..

Comment: I think this is the reason why books recommend it. When people override public methods, they do not expect to introduce side effects.

Answer (score 2):

I just summarize answers here and add some context:

- It is legal compile-wise to reuse public methods from public methods within the same class.
- It is considered a bad practice for API design,because it makes your class designed error-prone for inheritance given one may override one method without overriding another, breaking the logic of your class (this point is from one famous Java "best-practices" book "Effective Java" and it is well explained there and it is also well explained in another answer in this question)
- Also it is mentioned in another answer, you can not mock public method, so it may be concern for unit-testing

My 2 cents:

- Making a class "final" makes it not a bad practice anymore, as you do not design your API for inheritance.
- I don't see a concern with unit-testing, you can write your test the same way as you would write it if one of your methods is private.
- Another use-case where it can be a bad practice is when you use Spring Boot with some AOP annotations (@Transactional or @Async). Calling from public method another public method annotated with some AOP annotation may create subtle bugs when annotation is ignored and not used, and the code does not behave as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what he meant. You can obviously call a public method from another public method. It is not a bad idea - even Java's source has methods in which one public method calls another public method.

Why don't you ask the guy who advised you to explain the reason? I think he is in a better position to tell than we are.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can call any public method from another public method whether it is inside same class or another class. But standard does matter for different organization. Give him/her some valid example.