# What is the right way to unit-test a function that calls another public function on the same object?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns

While I am aware of this question/answers ([Unit testing a method that calls another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363596/unit-testing-a-method-that-calls-another-method)), still not sure what is the best approach to unit-test a method that calls another public method on the same class?

I made a sample code (it can be seen here too: [dotnetfiddle.net/I07RMg](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I07RMg) )

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public string Title { get; set;}
}

public interface IMyService
{
    MyEntity GetEntity(int entityId);
    IEnumerable<MyEntity> GetAllEntities();
}

public sealed class MyService : IMyService
{
    IRepository _repository;

    public MyService(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public MyEntity GetEntity(int entityId)
    {
        var entities = GetAllEntities();
        var entity = entities.SingleOrDefault(e => e.ID == entityId);

        if (entity == null)
        {
            entity = new MyEntity { ID = -1, Title = "New Entity" };
        }

        return entity;
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyEntity> GetAllEntities()
    {
        var entities = _repository.Get();

        //Some rules and logics here, like:

        entities = entities.Where(e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Title));
        return entities; // To broke the test: return new List<MyEntity>();
    }
}

public interface IRepository : IDisposable
{
    IEnumerable<MyEntity> Get();
}
```

So the question is how to write a unit test that only tests the logic inside `MyService.GetEntity(int)`? (while `GetEntity` internally calls `GetAllEntities()` but I am not interested to test latter one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test it by mocking function GetAllEntities(), using mocking framework (I use [Typemock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/)).

Here is a simple example:

```
[TestMethod, Isolated]
public void TestGetCreatesNewEntity()
{
    //Assert
    IRepository someRepository = new MyRepository();
    MyService service = new MyService(someRepository);

    List<MyEntity> entities = new List<MyEntity>();
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => service.GetAllEntities()).WillReturn(entities.AsQueryable());

    //Act
    MyEntity result = service.GetEntity(1);

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(-1, result.ID);
    Assert.AreEqual("New Entity", result.Title);
}
```

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: JamesR - hmmm. I use `Moq` [ https://github.com/moq/moq4 ]. I should see if this is possible with my mocking framework.

Comment: JamesR - It seems that Moq doesn't have this feature but there's another way (`.CallBase()`), that can go around it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2462672/538387
I will test it an let you know if it works.

Comment: JamesR - Turns out that TypeMock is the only well-known framework that supports mocking concrete `sealed` classes. Moq cannot do that. Thank you anyway. +1 up.

Comment: That's why I'm using it. You're welcome, hope u'll enjoy it too

Answer (score 7):

I really believe that unit testing isn't about mocking even methods of the same class.

When we talk about *units* we should refer to *parts of your software*. That is, you want to test `GetEntity` and the fact that it also calls `GetAllEntities` under the hoods is just an implementation detail.

What you really need is to be sure that, when you test your service, any injected dependency (repository, other services collaborating in the domain...) should be replaced with fakes to be sure that you're just testing your service, or you'll be implementing an *integration test*.

### OP said in some comment...

> I understand. The only caveat is if the logics inside the
>   GetAllEntities() fails, it might also breaks Unit Tests for
>   GetEntity(). Then it's a bit harder to pin point where the real bug
>   lies.

As I said previously on this answer, the fact that `GetEntity` calls `GetAllEntities` is just an implementation detail. It's like if you would re-implement (argh, copy-paste programming...) the logic of `GetAllEntities` inside `GetEntity`. Who cares.

Actually, if `GetEntity` fails because `GetAllEntities`, the test for `GetAllEntities` itself will also fail. What test will you try to address first? I suspect that once you've realized that `GetEntities` fails because of `GetAllEntities` and also `GetAllEntities` test fails, you would go directly to fix `GetAllEntities` test, won't you?

In summary, the way you've described your concern, the *bug* would be on `GetAllEntities` and it's absolutely expectable that any other method relying on `GetAllEntities` could fail too.

Comment: I understand. The only caveat is if the logics inside the `GetAllEntities()` fails, it might also breaks Unit Tests for `GetEntity()`. Then it's a bit harder to pin point where the real bug lies.

Comment: Matias Fidermaizer - Please take a look at JamesR's answer. I do like it better, but unfortunately TypeMock is the only mocking framework that supports it, as far as I find out.

Comment: @Tohid This is up to you, my humble opinion is you shouldn't be that paranoic, and at the end of the day, you'll end up mocking too much and, just think what are you really testing? If some method calls other and the caller has, for example, 3 lines of code, that test will be practically useless.

Comment: @Tohid If you feel that mocking at the whole level as suggested by the other answer works better in your scenario, there's no problem, StackOverflow has the right answer for you and others that can be also useful for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

You can increase your design and testeability creating a virtual GetAllEntities methods, subclass your service with MyTesteableService:

```
public class MyTesteableService : MyService
{
    public override IEnumerable<MyEntity> GetAllEntities()
    {
        return something;
    }
}
```

Now you can test your new testeable service without use GetAllEntities logic.
however, you will have to test the behavior of GetEntity and verify the call to GetAllEntities.

So, in another manner, you can think your service as an abstract class with virtual GetEntity and abstract GetAllEntities. I use RhinoMock and I can do this with PartialMock (http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Partial+Mocks.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Comment: You aware that `MyService` is a sealed class, correct?

Comment: yes, my example is to explain design. If you really need to make your service sealed, then create a baseService with abstract GetAllEntities like my second concept: "in another manner, you can think your service as an abstract class..."